# How do I create a rake task for a Rails engine which is not exposed to the host application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, ruby-on-rails-plugins

```
# lib/tasks/test.rake
task :hello do
  puts 'hello'
end
```

$ rake app:hello

To run the task I need to prefix it with "app:" and it runs in the context of the dummy app. It is also exposed to the host application (i.e when used as a plugin in a parent Rails app) as `rake hello`.

I want to run a rake task which does not require a Rails environment and runs some command, but it is run from the engine root, not the dummy app root.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know that's a bit late, but for others here searching for the correct answer, do the following :

Create your task :

```
# lib/tasks/your_engine_tasks.rake
desc "Explaining what the task does"
task :your_task do
  # Task goes here
end
```

Then go to your engine ./Rakefile and add

```
load 'lib/tasks/your_engine_tasks.rake'
```

Here we go, now:

```
$ rake -T
```

gives you your task.

Hope I helped.

Comment: You need to add :environment to your task:

`task your_task: :environment do`

Answer (score 4):

I want a better answer to this question however I did figure out that you can add tasks in the Rakefile for the engine (so ./Rakefile not in the spec/dummy application) like so:

```
task :my_task do
  puts "hi!"
end

task :default => [:spec, :my_task]
```

I would prefer to have my task in another file but at least this provides a way to go forward. In my case, I want to run Konacha javascript tests in the dummy application so my Rakefile looks like this:

```
task :spec_javascript do
  exec 'cd spec/dummy && rake konacha:run' # exec passes command return value up stack!
end

task :default => [:spec, :spec_javascript]
```